# cannot login on website from mobile browser nokia 5800

Tags: php, mobile, mobile-website, login-script

**Does anyone recognize this problem.**

If I try to login on my mobile it reloads and sends me rightback to the index/login page.
The script recognizes a mobile browser and it will show a different indexpage.
I have tested everything with firefox while using the switch user-agent addon.

So, No problems working from a normal browser, 
except when I try to login on my mobile like I sayd.

Is there something that I should change In my loginscript because the mobile browsers can't handle it??

thanks, Richard

Comment: can you please post some relevant code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like that phone doesn't support cookies.

Comment: Thanks, Is that a problem with php? Is there a way around this?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a PHP issue. Not knowing anything about the specific phone, I can't be sure it's a cookie issue, but from your description that's what sounds likely.

Comment: I just read something about, it seems the standaard s60 browser on the 5800 does not support cookies. I wilL go check out opera mini then.

Comment: It was actually something else. The browser was sort of in a locked state. After I stopped sending packets, and started the browser up again it was working.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, what you need to do to fix it however is fairly simple.

Direct your mobile browser to http://m.twitter.com (their mobile site)

And it will work. Happy Twitting! :D